# xcode 4.5 not supporting in mac os x 10.7.3

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have updated the xcode 4.3.2 to 4.5 . I have mac version 10.7.3. dmg file which i have downloaded is not recognized by the mac . So I have to update the mac version also so from which version mac supports Xcode 4.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm running Xcode 4.5.1 on my iMac with OS X 10.7.5. Do a software update on your Mac to get the latest OS X 10.7.x. That should allow you to install Xcode 4.5.1.

Comment: can you please give me steps ?

Comment: Click on the Apple logo in the top left of your screen. Select Software Update.

Comment: it's for $19.99 right ?

Comment: No. It's free. It just a bug fix update. This isn't Mountain Lion. just an update to Lion.

Comment: ok in software update i got mac os x updated combine 10.7.5 isn't this ?

Comment: Yes, apply that update and then you can install Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

See [this link](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12). It is clearly mentioned that `Requirements: OS X 10.7.4 or later. You just need to do a software update by clicking the Apple menu.